# I am getting an error in rest assured automation in eclipse using testng

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:202)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getInt(JsonPath.java:237)
at ComplexJsonParse.main(ComplexJsonParse.java:12)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 3, column: 4, while reading '+', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:86)
at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseObject(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:227)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.this$2$parseObject(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:198)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:105)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
... 5 more

import files.payload;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

public class ComplexJsonParse {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    JsonPath js2 = new JsonPath(payload.CoursePrice());
    //Print number of courses returned by API
    
    int count = js2.getInt("courses.size()");
    System.out.println(count);
    
    //Print Purchase Amount
```

I was expecting 3